# Given an array of booleans, what is the most efficient way to select the index of a random TRUE value?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

You're given an array of size n, containing arbitrary boolean values.

What is the fastest way to return the index of a random TRUE value.

The algorithm should randomly return any one of the indices containing a TRUE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
int count = 0;
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
{
    if (values[i])
    {
        ++count;
        if (unit_random <= 1.0f / count)
        {
            index = i;
        }
    }
}
```

So for 4 values for example you get the following probabilities for their indices:

```
1: (1 / 1) * (1 / 2) * (2 / 3) * (3 / 4) = 1 / 4 
2: (1 / 2) * (2 / 3) * (3 / 4) = 1 / 4
3: (1 / 3) * (3 / 4) = 1 / 4
4: 1 / 4 = 1 / 4
```

**EDIT:** As Steve Jessop pointed out the floating point comparision will eventually lead to a very non uniform selection. Assuming `unit_random` is defined as `rand() / RAND_MAX` the comparision can be changed to:

```
typedef unsigned long long u64;
u64 product = u64(count) * rand();
if (product <= u64(RAND_MAX))
```

This won't give perfect distribution due to the discrete nature of `rand` but it will be better.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a word.  I meant to say: return the index of a random TRUE value...Not just the first one we find.  But the function should randomly return any one of the indices containing a TRUE.

Comment: @PaulV That's exactly what this function does.

Comment: Out of interest, how big does `count` have to be before this gives significantly non-uniform distribution at float precision? I'll let you pick your own meaning of "significant".

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution - assuming you don't select repeatedly on the same array - is to pick a random index, return it if it's true, and repeat if not. In the best case, where all entries are true, this is O(1); in the worst case, where only one entry is true, this is O(n) (each try has a 1/n chance of hitting the only true value, which means an expected number of tries of n). This is no worse than any of the other posted solutions.

If you expect the array to usually be almost all false, though, you may want to pick another solution, as the variance in runtime of this random method will be high.

Comment: "This is no worse than any of the other posted solutions" - the complexity isn't, but it uses cache less efficiently than Andreas's answer. And FWIW, Andreas's code catches the failure case, and this approach doesn't. Maybe the "best" thing (trading off expected vs. worst case) is to perform a small number of random samples, and if none of them finds a true value then conclude that the array is sparse, and fall back to Andreas's solution or similar.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what "randomly distibuted" means. Does it mean "with some unknown distribution"? If so, let's pretend all possible distributions are equally probable, so the "expected distribution" (like in "expected value") is uniform (the "average" of all possible distributions.) Then any index is TRUE with a probability of 1/2. So your task becomes the task of iterating through the array as quickly as possible. Start at the beginning, like you would normally iterate an array, until you encounter a TRUE value.

Comment: I meant there is no pattern to the values.  They do not follow any sort of distribution function.

Comment: Guess that means [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)), right? ;)

Comment: @PaulV: "randomly distributed" is probably a bad phrase to use if you mean "they do not follow any sort of distribution function". You could have said "arbitrary boolean values", or just "boolean values". Then you would have to define what you mean by "fastest", because if you don't have a distribution for the values then there is no such thing as "expected runtime" for any algorithm whose speed depends on the values.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return it, you must first count the True values (there is not way to skip that) and accumulate their indices in another array. And after counting you need to just generate random integer from 0 to N-1 (where N is the number of True values) and pick the value from the created array.

in pseudo-python:

```
indices=[]

for i,val in enumerate(arr):
    if val:
       indices.append(i)
randi = randint(0,len(indices)-1)
return indices[randi]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: Generate a permutation of possible indexes (1:n ?) and in the order of that permutation return index if the corresponding value is true

```
def randomTrue(x):
    perm = randomPermute(0:len(x))
    for i in perm:
         if x[i]:
             return i
```